# Custom GNOME applet in Python needs to have root privileges

Tags: gnome, applet, root

I've written a custom GNOME panel applet in Python that needs to write to some root-owned files. Is there a way to make it start with root privileges without using suid?

Comment: Can't you just launch it gksudo and add a rule into /etc/sudoers to not request for a password ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [PolicyKit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PolicyKit).

- [Library Reference](http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/PolicyKit/)

Answer (score 1):

Better solution: do not run whole applet with root permissions. Put everything possible to applet which is running with normal user permissions. Create separate program that modifies necessary files, and run that through `sudo` (or suid).

For sudoers configuration, run `visudo`. Try something like

```
yourusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/your_command.py
```

To allow running specific commands with root permissions.

---

Another way: add file acl to those root owned files to allow changes by your user.

See `man setfacl` for more information (from package `acl`).

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the procedures that require root access into a separate python program and launch that with `gksudo`.

[I asked a similar question on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4112737/477933)